# Using Mooncake Template

Tags: asp.net, html, templates

Here is the Mooncake template link: [Mooncake template](http://themeforest.net/item/mooncake-responsive-admin-template/3138068). Has anyone ever used it? I'm trying to apply this template to my ASP.NET website, using ASP.NET controls, but I have some problems about this.

First, in the `Forget password` menu, when a user clicks the `Reset` button, it will post back to the server and do some validations. If it doesn't pass the validations, the form will be displayed again with error messages. The problem is when the page reloads, it changes back to the default view, which is `Login` menu, so I have to change to `Forget password` menu to see the error messages. How can I make it display `Forget password` menu directly?

The second thing is how can I apply table format to my grid view? The column of a table in this template can be sorted without posting back by clicking on the header.
Any of your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)